# How to configure Send-Only mail server in Linux which will accept and perform email delivery for multiple application/web servers in same network

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sendmail, postfix-mta, mta

I've one Web server, one Middleware server and one backend application server in same subnet/network. All these three servers needs to send notification alert emails to multiple email IDs like GMAIL, Yahoo, Outlook etc. for this I've to configure sendmail server on each server separately.

Is it possible if I can deploy one small dedicated sendmail or postfix server which will accept and perform email delivery for all three servers, I'll just change mail server IP address to this dedicated mail servers IP in middleware code, web server configuration and backend application so that these servers will be able use mail server for every outgoing notification or alert email?

Kindly check and please guide me how it can be configure.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I have such a configuration using Postfix.

Postfix on every non-mailserver is configured to use a **relayhost**. It passes all mail through to the relayhost. By having Postfix on all servers, local (non-SMTP) mail delivery forwarded to an e-mail address works as well (e.g. an error message from a cron job).

The servers that are allowed to send mail are configured in **mynetworks** in main.cf on the mail server. This is important, so your mail server doesn't become an open relay.

Comment: Thanks Rene! Could please guide me what installation and configuration I need to perform on dedicate mail server and other application servers? Please share how-to link which I can refer. I'm Sorry If I'm bothering to you! I'm a newbie to Linux. Thanks again.